# nginx-ingress failing intermittely

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

nginx-ingress failing intermittely

---

**NGINX Ingress controller version:** 0.22.0

**Image:** quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.22.0

**Image ID:** docker-pullable://quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller@sha256:47ef793dc8dfcbf73c9dee4abfb87afa3aa8554c35461635f6539c6cc5073b2c

quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller

**Kubernetes version (use kubectl version):** v1.15.3

---

**Environment:**

**Cloud provider or hardware configuration:** Vm's in Vcenter

**OS (e.g. from /etc/os-release):** VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"

**Kernel (e.g. uname -a):** Linux appsec-ana01 4.4.0-143-generic #169-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 7 07:56:38 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Install tools:

Others:

**What happened:** my nginx-ingress-controller is failing and restarting inconsistently..

**What you expected to happen:** No Restart to happen

**How to reproduce it (as minimally and precisely as possible):** Same Version issue should occur.

```
curl -I http://10.244.10.48:10254/healthz
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 11 Sep 2019 11:15:56 GMT
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

**Anything else we need to know:**

kubectl get events results in following

```
2m Warning Unhealthy pod/nginx-ingress-controller-7cfb747d6c-4n4nz Liveness probe failed: Get http://10.244.10.48:10254/healthz: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
30s Warning Unhealthy pod/nginx-ingress-controller-7cfb747d6c-4n4nz Liveness probe failed: Get http://10.244.10.48:10254/healthz: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
6m5s Warning Unhealthy pod/nginx-ingress-controller-7cfb747d6c-4n4nz Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.244.10.48:10254/healthz: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
35m Warning Unhealthy pod/nginx-ingress-controller-7cfb747d6c-4n4nz Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.244.10.48:10254/healthz: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

curl -I http://10.244.10.48:10254/healthz
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 11 Sep 2019 11:15:56 GMT
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: This question can't be read. Please format your post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

The errors in you logs clearly say about health check issues with a particular `nginx-ingress-controller*` Pod. Due to the fact that *Readiness* and *Liveness* [probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) are fully managed by [kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) node agent, I would check carefully `kubelet` service, in order to fetch any related errors or suspicious events:

`$ sudo systemctl status kubelet -l`

`$ sudo journalctl -u kubelet`

Therefore, the issue may occurs with a connectivity from `kubelet` node to K8s API server, despite your successful efforts testing `curl` requests targeting `/health` endpoint.

Meanwhile, you can check logs from [Nginx Ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) controller's Pod and inspect bootstrap events:

`kubectl logs $(kubectl get po -l app=nginx-ingress -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}')`

I would also check the K8s [Node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#node-status) capacity where origin `nginx-ingress-controller*` Pod resides on and observe overall resource utilization for allocated objects across the cluster.

I recommend you to review the official *Nginx Ingress-Controller* troubleshooting [document](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/troubleshooting/) to get more ways for investigation.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's not connected with Nginx controller but rather with Kubernetes node. Have you seen this?

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/70324